# 2sxc How to use a value from the App Settings in Visual Query?

Tags: 2sxc

I've the latest version of 2sxc (8.11) and I can't use an App Settings value in a filter on the Visual Query.

I've tried using [App:Settings:VariableName] but it keeps giving a bad request error message ("Input string was not in a correct format"). I've tried to change the variable type (text and number) but the error is always the same.

I want to use the App Setting to send some static information to a lot of queries (the AppId of an App, for example) and, if needed, change that information in only one place.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question!

There is no special feature for this, but it's still easy to do :).

The App Settings is a content-item of the type "App-Settings" in the same-named scope "2SexyContent-App". If you ever want to look into it *directly*, just change scopes to "2SexyContent-App" - here's how to do it: http://2sxc.org/en/Blog/post/advanced-dynamic-data-content-understanding-content-type-scopes

To use it as a parameter, you would need use a content-type-filter to get "all" of these (there is only one), and use the result as an In-parameter for another part - here's how: http://2sxc.org/en/Docs/Feature/feature/4544

That should do it :)

Comment: To access the App Settings you need to use an "Entity Type Filter" and write "App-Settings" as value in TypeName. That worked for me!